# It's there a documented case of someone who learned language from the written word?

Tags: language, cognitive-development

I'm wondering whether there is any known case of someone who was unable to communicate through speech or sign language (e.g. because of a lack of people around then who knew sign language), and who learned language for the first time via the written word only.

Comment: And with or without Rosetta stone equivalents?